# MySQL select statement returning multiple SUM with multiple WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.  The first contains an inventory list (items), and the second a history of sales (invoiceLines).

```
+--------------------+  +--------------------+
|        items       +  +    invoiceLines    +
+--------------------+  +--------------------+
+ id                 +  + itemCode           +
+ itemDesc           +  + qtyShipped         +
+ qtyOnHandW1        +  + invDate            +
+--------------------+  +--------------------+
```

I can get the data I want with separate queries, like this one:

```
SELECT itemCode, itemDesc, ROUND(SUM(qtyShipped)) as m11
FROM invoiceLines
WHERE invDate >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND invDate <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MONTH)
AND itemCode = 001
GROUP BY itemCode;
```

However, I want to return id, itemDesc, qtyOnHandW1 from items,
along with the SUM or qtyShipped during this month last year (m12), this month +1m last year (m11), and this month +2m last year (m10).

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    id    |     itemDesc      |   qtyOH  |  m12   |  m11  |  m10   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
+ 001      | product A         |    50    |   32   |   25  |   70   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
+ 002      | product B         |    31    |   16   |   31  |   41   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
+ 003      | product C         |    5     |   22   |   11  |    3   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try changing your query to something like this...assuming you are looking for months referenced in 2017....

```
SELECT 
 a.itemCode as itemCode, 
 a.itemDesc as itemCode, 
 (select ROUND(SUM(qtyShipped)) 
  from invoiceLines 
  where date_format(invDate,'%Y%m') = '201712' and itemCode = a.itemCode 
  group by date_format(invDate,'%Y%m'),itemCode ) as m12,
 (select ROUND(SUM(qtyShipped)) 
  from invoiceLines 
  where date_format(invDate,'%Y%m') = '201711' and itemCode = a.itemCode
  group by date_format(invDate,'%Y%m'),itemCode ) as m11,
 (select ROUND(SUM(qtyShipped)) 
  from invoiceLines 
  where date_format(invDate,'%Y%m') = '201710' and itemCode = a.itemCode
  group by date_format(invDate,'%Y%m'),itemCode ) as m10 
FROM invoiceLines as a
AND a.itemCode = 001
GROUP BY a.itemCode;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to some sample data it's difficult to respond but this query should work:

```
SELECT i.id, i.itemDesc, i.qtyOnHandW1, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN l.invDate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH) THEN l.qtyShipped ELSE 0 END) AS m12,
   SUM(CASE WHEN l.invDate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MONTH) THEN l.qtyShipped ELSE 0 END) AS m11,
   SUM(CASE WHEN l.invDate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MONTH) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 9 MONTH) THEN l.qtyShipped ELSE 0 END) AS m10
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN invoiceLines l
ON l.itemCode = i.id
GROUP BY i.id
```

Here's a [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eeff55b/1) with some sample data I created.

Comment: Thank you! This got me where I needed to go.